# why does memory address change in Ubuntu and not in Redhat

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gdb, redhat

I have this program:

```
double t;
main() {
}
```

On **Ubuntu**, I run:

```
% gdb a.out
(gdb) p &t
$1 = (double *) 0x4010 <t>
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/phan/a.out 
[Inferior 1 (process 95930) exited normally]
(gdb) p &t
$2 = (double *) 0x555555558010 <t>
```

Why did the address change from `0x4010` to `0x555555558010`. Is there someway to prevent this?
On **Redhat**, it doesn't do that:

```
% gdb a.out
(gdb) p &t
$1 = (double *) 0x601038 <t>
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/phan/a.out 
[Inferior 1 (process 23337) exited normally]
(gdb) p &t
$2 = (double *) 0x601038 <t>
```

BTW, this only occurs in **Ubuntu 18.04**.  In **Ubuntu 16.04**, it works exactly as Redhat, for example the address is the same before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are presumably seeing pre and post-relocation addresses for the `.bss` segment.

You can avoid this by disabling position independent executables, thus making `gcc` choose the final address of the `.bss` register up front:

```
gcc -no-pie foo.c
```

`-static` would have the effect.

I don't know why there'd be a difference between Ubuntu and Redhat though.

Comment: The difference is because Ubuntu configures its GCC to produce PIE binaries by default, while RedHat does not.